# rainfall seasonality index in R

Tags: r, equation

This is probably a more general question of how to code equations in R, but I'll apply the concept to what's been on my to-do list. We are examining the rainfall seasonality of a monthly time series of rainfall, which measures how one month in a given year rainfall differs than if each month received 1/12 of the annual rainfall. The equation can be found here: http://leddris.aegean.gr/ses-parameters/293-rainfall-seasonality.html but re-written here: [rainfall seasonality](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaOze.jpg)

Where Si is the annual seasonality index, Ri is the total annual precipitation for the particular year under study and Xin is the actual monthly precipitation for month n.

Our data has the below structure and continues monthly through water year 2014

```
head(monthlyRain)
  MonthofYr WaterYear monthlyRain
          1      1983     289.2
          2      1983     150.8
          3      1983     134.3
          4      1983      16.1
          5      1983     490.3
          6      1983     328.9
```

As mentioned above, this is a more general question about how to solve slightly complex equations in R, using an example I have at hand. Let me know if this cross-posted or if there are other links to solve without being redundant here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in understanding seasonality, monthplot and/or stl functions are good options in R. 
https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.1/topics/monthplot

https://otexts.org/fpp2/seasonal-subseries-plots.html